# Differentiating between username and userid in widget

Tags: stocktwits

I'm noticing issues with widgets displaying the wrong data for users whose username starts with a number. The widget looks like it is treating them as if it is the user id.

Is there a way to differentiate when using a username over a user id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **user** parameter can be either a username or an id. At least it should. You are correct the numbers of the username are getting confused. We will fix the issue and report back. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Nice one Chris. Works as expected now.